# Display notification (e.g. messagebox) while application is being closed

Tags: c#, wpf

In my application, I am overriding the `OnClose` event the way shown below. Since the application can take some time to perform `SynchronizeLotsaStuff`, I want to notify the user that application will soon close.

I tried with a MessageBox, but that blocks the continuation of the program, and also displays an "OK" button that is not desired.

I guess I would prefer something more characteristic, such as fading/graying the window, or even a "splash screen" for closing, but a regular messagebox would be fine too.

```
// MainWindow.xaml.cs:

protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Wait while application is closed...");
    if (this.DataContext != null) {
        var vm = this.DataContext as ShellViewModel;
        // possibly long-running method
        vm.SynchronizeLotsaStuff();
    }
    base.OnClosing(e);
}
```

UPDATE: Following Stijn Bernards advice, I put the MessageBox stuff inside a thread, but I haven't found (yes I googled) a proper way to terminate it. Even if `Abort`, the MessageBox keeps displaying after MainWindow has closed, until I click "OK" button.

```
// MainWindow.xaml.cs:

protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var messagethread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {
        MessageBox.Show("Aguarde enquanto o aplicativo é encerrado...");
    }));

    messagethread.Start();

    if (this.DataContext != null) {
        var vm = this.DataContext as ShellViewModel;
        // possibly long-running method
        vm.SynchronizeLotsaStuff();
    }

    // UGLY UGLY UGLY (and doesn't work either)
    messagethread.Abort();

    base.OnClosing(e);
}
```

Comment: There are plenty of resources on google for a splash screen.. whats your question?

Comment: @Sayse Question is how to display a modal but non-blocking notification that automatically disappears when application closes.

Comment: stick the sync method into a background worker and on the `runworkercompleted` event, close the splash screen

Comment: Create new window, show it with required info?

Comment: Block the main thread(show spinning), do sync in working thread the come back, unblock and close then application.

Comment: run the message box in another thread when your onclosing is finished finally stop the message box thread

Comment: @StijnBernards I decided to follow your suggestion, but I guess I haven't found a good way to "stop the messagebox thread" as you said...

Comment: @heltonbiker let my post an answer

Comment: @StijnBernards When you have a long running operation to do and a UI you want to show when doing it you do the long running operation in a background thread and display the UI in the UI thread, you don't display the UI in a background thread and do your long running non-UI work in the UI thread.

Comment: @Servy well that makes sense... Worth a try. But still the lack of a handle to close MessageBox is being a problem...

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using the abort thread and to my suprises it isn't working.

And well I can say it doesn't look easy...

So I advice to look into this: [click me](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8460/Advanced-MessageBoxing-with-the-C-MessageBoxIndire)

It's a good tutorial about how to create your own message box, which would then also help you with your problem of removing the ok button.

Cheers.